# C fread() on short file is producing junk after the file ends

Tags: c, file, fread

My professor specified that `file_1.txt` be read `100` bytes at a time into a `char array`. I produced the following snippet code :

```
int key;
key = atoi(argv[1]);
FILE *file_pointer;
file_pointer = fopen(argv[2], "rb");
char buffer[100];
char output[sizeof(int)][100];
int output_counter = 0;
int read_counter;
int read_elements;

while(read_elements = fread(buffer, 1, 100, file_pointer) > 0)
{  
    read_counter = 0;    
    while(read_counter < 100)
    {

        printf("xor'ing %d and %d\n", key, buffer[read_counter]);
        output[output_counter][read_counter] = buffer[read_counter] ^ key;
        read_counter = read_counter + 1;
    }

    output_counter = output_counter + 1;
}

fclose(file_pointer);
```

`file_1.txt` reads : "test file for the project\n". I used `gcc` `encrypt.c` 
Then :

```
./a.out 111 file_1.txt file_2.txt
```

Then :
    ./a.out 111 file_2.txt file_3.txt

```
cat file_3.txt reads:
```

**test file for the project :**

v▒▒▒s▒▒ @////////▒

During the first run of the program with `file_1.txt` and `file_2.txt`, the print statement in the nested while loop printed:

```
xor'ing 111 and 116

xor'ing 111 and 101

xor'ing 111 and 115

xor'ing 111 and 116

xor'ing 111 and 32

xor'ing 111 and 102

xor'ing 111 and 105

xor'ing 111 and 108

xor'ing 111 and 101

xor'ing 111 and 32

xor'ing 111 and 102

xor'ing 111 and 111

xor'ing 111 and 114

xor'ing 111 and 32

xor'ing 111 and 116

xor'ing 111 and 104

xor'ing 111 and 101

xor'ing 111 and 32

xor'ing 111 and 112

xor'ing 111 and 114

xor'ing 111 and 111

xor'ing 111 and 106

xor'ing 111 and 101

xor'ing 111 and 99

xor'ing 111 and 116

xor'ing 111 and 10

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 118

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and -88

xor'ing 111 and -31

xor'ing 111 and -94

xor'ing 111 and 2

xor'ing 111 and -120

xor'ing 111 and 127

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and -57

xor'ing 111 and 115

xor'ing 111 and -33

xor'ing 111 and 2

xor'ing 111 and -120

xor'ing 111 and 127

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 1

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and -19

xor'ing 111 and 9

xor'ing 111 and 64

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 47

xor'ing 111 and 47

xor'ing 111 and 47

xor'ing 111 and 47

xor'ing 111 and 47

xor'ing 111 and 47

xor'ing 111 and 47

xor'ing 111 and 47

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and 0

xor'ing 111 and -96

xor'ing 111 and 9

xor'ing 111 and 64

xor'ing 111 and 0
```

Where did these `random` elements come from?

Comment: Sorry about the super long prints btw

Comment: If you put them in a code block, they'll be scrollable.

Comment: You XOR exactly 100 bytes (`while(read_counter < 100)`), regardless to the actual amounts of bytes (`read_elements`) you read from file. So the trash comes from the uninitialized part of `read_buffer[]`.

Comment: There's also a precedence error, so `read_elements` is always `1` in the loop.

Comment: If the junk is coming from the uninitialized part of the read_buffer char array, should I initialize all values to 0 at the start?

Comment: No, you should only process as many characters as were actually read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initializing all elements of the buffer char array to 0 before using fread() got rid of the junk.