# Variable int key inexplicably changing after being used as one input in XOR operation multiple times

Tags: c

I'm trying to encrypt `file_1.txt` with an inputted key and output the result to `file_2.txt`. The professor specified that the file had to be read in 100 bytes at a time.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
int key;
key = atoi(argv[1]);

FILE *file_pointer;
file_pointer = fopen(argv[2], "rb");

char buffer[100];
char output[sizeof(int)][100];
int output_counter = 0;
int read_counter;
int read_elements;
int buffer_reset_counter;
for(buffer_reset_counter = 0; buffer_reset_counter < 100; buffer_reset_counter++){
    buffer[buffer_reset_counter] = 0;
    }
while(read_elements = fread(buffer, 1, 100, file_pointer) > 0){
    read_counter = 0;
    while(read_counter < 100){
        printf("xor'ing %d and %d\n", key, buffer[read_counter]);
        output[output_counter][read_counter] = buffer[read_counter] ^ key;
        read_counter = read_counter + 1;
        }
    output_counter = output_counter + 1;
    for(buffer_reset_counter = 0; buffer_reset_counter < 100; buffer_reset_counter++){
        buffer[buffer_reset_counter] = 0;
        }
}

fclose(file_pointer);

file_pointer = fopen(argv[3], "wb");
int write_counter = 0;
while(write_counter < output_counter){
    fwrite(output[write_counter], 1, 100, file_pointer);
    write_counter = write_counter + 1;
    }
}
```

`file_1.txt` is the string `"test file for testing\n"` repeated 100 times.

The output of the prints were as expected for the first few hundred prints, but then the key changed:

```
xor'ing 111 and 115
xor'ing 111 and 116
xor'ing 111 and 105
xor'ing 111 and 110
xor'ing 111 and 103
xor'ing 111 and 10
xor'ing 111 and 116
xor'ing 111 and 101
xor'ing 111 and 115
xor'ing 111 and 116
xor'ing 111 and 32
xor'ing 111 and 102
xor'ing 111 and 105
xor'ing 111 and 108
xor'ing 111 and 101
xor'ing 111 and 32
xor'ing 111 and 102
xor'ing 111 and 111
xor'ing 111 and 114
xor'ing 111 and 32
xor'ing 111 and 116
xor'ing 111 and 101
xor'ing 111 and 115
xor'ing 111 and 116
xor'ing 111 and 105
xor'ing 6 and 110
xor'ing 26630 and 103
xor'ing 6383622 and 10
xor'ing 207710214 and 116
xor'ing 207710214 and 101
xor'ing 207710214 and 115
xor'ing 207710214 and 116
xor'ing 207710214 and 32
xor'ing 207710214 and 102
xor'ing 207710214 and 105
xor'ing 207710214 and 108
xor'ing 207710214 and 101
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I don't know how key is changing. In case it is relevant, `printf("%d", sizeof(int));` outputted 4.

Earlier I submitted a question (stackoverflow.com/q/47732691/905902) regarding junk getting into the buffer array because it was not initialized before using fread(). The problem this time is that key is changing unexpectedly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47732691/905902 duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C fread() on short file is producing junk after the file ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732691/c-fread-on-short-file-is-producing-junk-after-the-file-ends)

Comment: That was me earlier when I was having a problem with junk elements coming from an uninitialized array. The problem this time is with the key variable changing unexpectedly.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` as an array dimension seems wrong. On just about all modern systems it will equal to `4`. That is, `output` is an array of ***four*** elements, each element being another array of `100` character. In other words, `char output[4][100];`.

Comment: How would I go about having the maximum sized array there? The professor specified that the file would have to be read 100 bytes at a time into a char array, so I don't think I can use a linked list.

Comment: ***Also*** the expression `read_elements = fread(...) > 0` is equal to `read_elements = (fread(...) > 0)` due to [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). That is, you assign the result of the `>` comparison` to `read_elements`. This is seldom what one wants.

Comment: @Eagle_Bacon: you won't need to hold the whole `xor`'d result in memory if you write the 100 bytes of each `xor` result as soon as they're computed.  I.e., declare `char output[100]`, then just above where you increment `read_counter` do `fwrite(output, 1, 100, fOut);`, assuming `FILE *fOut = fopen(argv[3],"wb")` somewhere earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement:

```
output[output_counter][read_counter] = buffer[read_counter] ^ key;
```

`output_counter` can be greater than `sizeof(int)` if the loop it is in runs more than four times, i.e. there are more than 400 bytes (I think) in the file. When this happens the xor'ing operation overwrites the stack, which writes to the storage for `key`.

Higher level, you really want to learn to use a tool like `valgrind` or clang's address sanitizer as they will find issues like this very quickly.